# Which source control can be used to get code from TFS apart from TFVC?

Tags: java, merge, tfvc, team-explorer-everywhere

I merged 2 branches and there are no conflicts. I saw that there are no conflicts and immediately unchecked the auto resolution of conflicts.

I merged the branches again and still there are no conflicts.

[image]

After I opened the pending changes, I saw this. I think there should generally be a button or link for conflicts. But there is no such thing.

I have a lot of conflicting code. It is just keeping my version whenever I think there should be a conflict.

Can somebody tell me in their experience why conflicts are not shown to resolve even when there is conflicting code. Can I use another source control like GIT to perform the merge ? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

All of your changes have already been merged in your local workspace. As you can see in the pending changes list all changes there are marked with `[merge, ...]`.

If you want to perform the merge again, without any automatic merging you will have to first undo the pending changes. Then ensure that auto-merge is turned off, then perform the merge action again.

Given that the automatic merge succeeded, I'd expect that you still won't find any conflicts. It looks like TFVC is able to figure out all of your merges on its own based on the fact that the auto merge succeeded.

There is another possibility... If in the past you have merged with this branch and have chosen "Keep mine" then TFVC registers this choice and will keep this in mind in future merges. This can cause unexpected behaviour later if you weren't aware this was happening. The only way to undo these so-called "merge tickets" is to perform a Rollback on those previous merges. Without undoing these merge tickets you have one more option to force a merge on contents only, you'll need to perform the merge from the commandline and supply the `force` switch:

```
tf vc merge /recursive /force /noautoresolve $/Project/BranchA $/Project/BranchB
```